# How do I write a link that will open a new email addressed to a Outlook365 Contact Group

Tags: outlook

I can write:

`mailto://me@somewhere.com` which creates a link to the email composer window and populates the 'to' box with the specified address.

How can I achieve the same but use the name of a contact group? Outlook does have a floating window for the contact group that features a button with the same functionality, so it looks possible, I'm just not sure what else needs adding to the link to differentiate between an address and the name of the contact group.

Any thoughts?